# How to read output of a process as non root

Tags: linux, kubernetes, permissions

I would like to read the output of a process by doing `tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1` but as a non root user(running this inside a container). Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: from a container: then the owner for that /proc/xxx/fd/y matches your container's user ID, doesn't it?

Comment: @SYN yes, you are correct.

Comment: So the fd directory of pid has permissions "dr-x------  2 root  root  0 Jun 22 04:21 fd"

Comment: Kindly check [Linux File Permission](https://linuxize.com/post/understanding-linux-file-permissions/). As for your details, only root can access the fd directory. One way to resolve this is change the fd or ...fd/1 permision (using root account) to view/access file. Can you share also the file permission of ...fd/1?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Linux File Permission](https://linuxize.com/post/understanding-linux-file-permissions/).

As for your details, only root can access the fd directory. One way to resolve this is change the fd or ...fd/1 permision (using root account) to view/access file.